# How to apply input which has a type email to to HTML Helper in Asp.net MVC3 Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, input, razor

How to apply input which has a type email to HTML Helper in Asp.net MVC3 Razor.
For example:

```
 <input type="email" name="name" value=" " placeholder="example@mail.ru" />
```

Is there alternative in Razor?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [Html.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method.

```
@Html.TextBox("name","", new { type = "email", placeholder = "example@mail.ru" })
```

Comment: hmm, I didn't think that new {type="email"} work)). Thank you, @kardeş

Answer (score 11):

Use Dataanotations at Model :

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress
{
    get;
    set;

}
```

Comment: Thank you,@Naresh.But I knew this.

Comment: Just adding that in MVC 5 (and probably older ones) this works only with the EditorFor, if you use the TextBoxFor it ignores the DataType.

Answer (score 4):

The below code has worked for me perfectly. By default `@Html.TextBoxFor` creates `<input type="text" />` but specifying the `type="email"` property makes it `<input type="email" />`

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailId, new { @class = "popinputbox", placeholder = "Email ID", type = "email" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailId, "", new { @class = "errormsg" })
</div>
```

The problem gets solved. BINGO !!