# Email Validation for html helper - ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

I have an Asp.Net MVC project. I am trying to make an email validation for an editorFor.

Based on what i've researched the way [in this answer: [How to apply input which has a type email to to HTML Helper in Asp.net MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689955/how-to-apply-input-which-has-a-type-email-to-to-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc3-razo) and more...] to do it is like this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @dir="ltr", @type = "email"} })
```

The only issue is that this makes sure that i have this pattern:
**name@gmail**
but it doesn't make sure that there is a **.** in the email address somewhere after the **@** - [**name@gmail.com**].

any ideas about what i can do?
thanks

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16690164/1663001) answer on the post you linked?

Comment: Remove `new { @type = "email" }`and add the `[EmailAddress]` attribute to you property

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your model like this:

Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

```
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [EmailAddress]
        [RegularExpression("^[_A-Za-z'`+-.]+([_A-Za-z0-9'+-.]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-])+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.([A-Za-z]*){3,})$",ErrorMessage="Enter proper email")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Format not proper of email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

This will validate the email address properly i am using this.

Comment: I tried doing what you said @Sorangwala, but it's giving me an error - in the pattern, under the \  character there is a red line and when i hover over it it says: **Unrecognized escape sequence**. When i try running the program i get a "Compilation error" of: **Unrecognized escape sequence**.